# What is the purpose of a shebang

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Imagine someone would akso you following:

> A shell script begins with the line
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/ruby
> ```
>
> What is the purpose?

I wonder how to correctly aswer to that question in a short and compact way?
Could you just say:

This line represents a so called shebang which gives the operation system the information which interpreter should be used - in this case the ruby interpreter since the file will be a ruby file.

Or would you answer this question in a different way?

Any inout much appreciated,
Chris

I have tried to research the answer using google. Then I have tried to come up with an own answer. But stil lI am not sure how to go at best about answering this one.

Comment: The technical question about shebang behavior in on-topic, but already asked-and-answered elsewhere on the site (not to mention that you already know the answer yourself, at least in broad strokes); the request for concise wording is _not_ on-topic here, being more about the English language than software development; also, judging answers for best wording is opinion-centric and not technical in nature.

Comment: I _do_ think your proposed answer is acceptable, presuming (and you know this better than I do) that it's delivering at the level of detail expected in the context where the question was asked).

Comment: In essence, your answer is correct. Looking at it closely, the reason behind it is however the _magic number_ hiding in it. This is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Magic_number).